# get md5 hash of last column that has spaces from an input text file with 7 million rows

Tags: bash, awk, tabs, md5

I have a file with 7+ million rows of lines like this:

```
37831471       48 -rw-r-----    1 user            group               18212 Dec 12 16:24 path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/documents.wflow
37831472       16 -rw-r-----    1 user            group                 927 Dec 12 16:24 path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/Info.wflow
37831470       16 -rw-r-----    1 user            group                 136 Dec 12 16:24 path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/version.wflow
```

I need to get the 7th and 11th columns, and an MD5 hash of the 11th column string (not file). The 11th columns has spaces so I can't just reference it by a specific field so I have to empty specific columns and print the entire row. I need tab separated so I have to add tabs..

This is what I have so far and the output it gives:

```
cat -n test.txt | awk '{$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$9=$10=$11=""; $1=$1"\t"; $8=$8"\t"; print}'
```

And the output:

```
1              18212        path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/documents.wflow
2              927          path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/Info.wflow
3              136          path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/version.wflow
```

The only thing I can't figure out is how to get the MD5 hash of that 11th/last column. And I need the MD5 hash of the string in the 11th/last column -- not the file that it references.

I'd love to be able to trim the white spaces for each column but that is not necessary.

Comment: wrt `The only thing I can't figure out` - no, you also haven't figured out how to preserve spaces in your file names. What you're doing right now will convert all sequences of blanks and/or tabs in your file names to single blank chars. Include in your question how you'd get a "MD5 hash" of one of the strings you're interested in if you were doing it other than via awk parsing your file.

Comment: as you have filenames with spaces - you can't rely on fixed number of fields (11 or more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to really do what you're trying to do so far so it preserves spaces in that last string (I used variables named foo and bar as you didn't tell us what those strings are, change those names to suit):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{foo=$7; sub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){10}/,""); bar=$0; print NR, foo, bar}' file
1       18212   path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/documents.wflow
2       927     path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/Info.wflow
3       136     path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/version.wflow
```

To call some command on "bar" (I'm using `echo` below) might be:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{
    foo = $7
    sub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){10}/,"")
    bar = $0
    cmd = "echo \047" bar "\047"
    md5 = ( ((cmd | getline line) > 0) ? line : "N/A" )
    close(cmd)
    print NR, foo, bar, md5
}' file
1       18212   path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/documents.wflow    path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/documents.wflow
2       927     path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/Info.wflow path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/Info.wflow
3       136     path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/version.wflow      path/to/file with spaces and backslashes/folder\scn.workflow/version.wflow
```

but it all depends how your command works (e.g. does it take input as an argument, or from a file passed as an argument, or from a pipe, or something else, and does it process 1 line at a time, or all input at once, or something else) and there might be more efficient ways to get the same output depending on that.

Comment: I will try this but what about the md5 hash of the last column.

Comment: Exactly. I'm sure you have some command in mind that you want to call but you haven't told us what it is yet.

Comment: there is the `md5` command. would that work? is calling an external command the only way?

Comment: It depends what that external command does. If there's a builting awk function (e.g. log() or sqrt()) then of course you can just call that. With what I THINK you're trying to do you'd have to call the external command and I added a generic way to call external commands to my answer. If you edit your question to show what it is you're trying to do then I expect you'll be able to get more help on how to do that.

Comment: I am not trying to call any external command. I just need to add a column that has the MD5 hash of the last column in the file. I will give this a try.

Comment: So is the "MD5 hash" already present in your input file or does the tool need to look it up in some other file or what? You're really not giving us much to go on to be able to help you! Please edit your question to clarify your requirements and don't assume anyone knows what a "MD5 hash" is or where to find it in your input or environment.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I need but I think I can refactor to do what I need. I'm having issues with the regex but I'll open a new question for that.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not even consider that not everyone knows what an MD5 hash is. However, what I can use what you provided if I can get my regex to work. Thank you!

Comment: `md5` exists on some platforms, but not on others. On Linux you will probably find `md5sum`.  A common error is to include a newline in your input when you should not supply one; i.e. try `"printf '%s' \047" $11 "\047 | md5sum"` for `cmd`